# Пунктуация при "двойной" прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно расставить знаки препинания в следующих предложениях.

**1)** У вас могут возникнуть мысли: «А почему это я должен что-то делать, а не мой партнер?» - или страхи: «Ага, сейчас я уступлю, а потом он мне на шею сядет!»

**2)** Вместо того чтобы сказать тебе: «Давай подумаем, вместе мы найдем решение!» - тебе говорили: «Решай сам, не маленький!»

**3)** Она сказала: «Ну хорошо, пусть будет по-вашему» - и тихо добавила: «Как же вы мне надоели».

Интересуют места между репликами. Верно ли поставлены тире и вторые двоеточия?

Напишите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно.

Answer (score 3):

У Розенталя есть тема "Прямая речь внутри слов автора". Это схема А—П—А. В Вашем случае схема А—П—А—П, но я думаю, что добавление второй прямой речи на оформление не влияет.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

1) У вас могут возникнуть мысли: «А почему это я должен что-то делать, а не мой партнер?»  **или** страхи: «Ага, сейчас я уступлю, а потом он мне на шею сядет!»

Розенталь: Не говорить же: «Эй, собака!» или «Эй, кошка!» — **две реплики, разделенные неповторяющимся союзом или;**

2) Вместо того чтобы сказать тебе: «Давай подумаем, вместе мы найдем решение!» — тебе говорили: «Решай сам, не маленький!»

Розенталь: И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто легче (Ч.) — **тире после вопросительного/восклицательного знака,** которым заканчивается прямая речь;

Комментарий: Если бы не было восклицательного знака в прямой речи, то на месте тире ставилась бы запятая (это как бы "встроенная" прямая речь)

3) Она сказала: «Ну хорошо, пусть будет по-вашему» — и тихо добавила: «Как же вы мне надоели».

Розенталь: Она сказала: «Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку (Л. Т.) — **тире перед союзом и при однородных сказуемых;**

Comment: Спасибо. Есть сомнения по поводу первого предложения. Если бы там было просто "или", тогда было бы понятно. А там однородные подлежащие: "мысли" и "страхи". Может быть, все же тире?..

Comment: Я не вижу большой разницы между однородными подлежащими и однородными дополнениями. Основной структурой является предложение: У вас могут возникнуть мысли или страхи, оно определяет интонацию всего сообщения, и мы должны это подчеркнуть отсутствием паузы перед ИЛИ. Но это мои собственные предположения, так как найти точно подходящих примеров у классиков не удалось. А в этом  случае от сомнений трудно избавиться. Возможно, кто-нибудь еще найдет подходящую информацию или хотя бы примеры употребления таких конструкций в текстах.